What is the consistency strength of $L(\mathbb{R})\models$ "$\omega_1$ has tree property"?
Motivated by this question. For us "$\kappa$ has tree property" means any tree that has underlying set $\kappa$, height $\kappa$ and levels $<\kappa$ has a branch.
The strength of $\mathsf{ZF+}$ "$\omega_1$ has tree property" is exactly that of a weakly compact; the forcing direction is the same construction as Jech's making $\omega_1$ measurable. But what if we consider $L(\mathbb{R})$? Feel free to add $\mathsf{DC}$ if that matters.
More broadly, is there some statement $\varphi$ such that the strength of $L(\mathbb{R})\models\varphi$ is exactly a weakly compact? Note that
$\varphi=$ there exists a countable transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC+}$ "there is a weakly compact cardinal"
does not work, and is cheating anyway. If there turns out to be some other way of cheating, my next question would be whether there is a natural statement $\varphi$.

There are over a dozen common characterizations of weak compactness in ZFC, but they are not all equivalent in ZF+DC, so could you let us know which version of weakly compact you want?

@JoelDavidHamkins Thanks for reminding me. I chose to use the definition via tree property and added the requirement that the underlying set should be $\kappa$, since otherwise I don't see how measurability implies weak compactness. Is it necessary?

But the tree property alone is not equivalent to weak compactness even in ZFC, unless one also specifies that the cardinal is inaccessible. But $\omega_1$ is never inaccessible.

The definition Jech uses in his paper in which he proves $\omega_1$ can be weakly compact or measurable (each relative to such a large cardinal in ZFC) is the partition characterization: an uncountable well-ordered cardinal $\kappa$ is weakly compact if $\kappa \rightarrow (\kappa)^2_2.$

Suppose $V=L$ and $\kappa$ is weakly compact. Force with the Levy collapse below $\kappa$. Then in $M=L(\mathbb{R}^{L[G]})$, $\omega_1$ has the tree property. For if $T\in M$ is a tree of the relevant kind, then $T\in\mathrm{HOD}^{L[G]}_{\{x\}}$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}^{L[G]}$ (since $M=L(\mathbb{R})^{L[G]}$). Let $\alpha<\kappa$ be such that $x\in L[G\upharpoonright\alpha]$. Then $T\in L[G\upharpoonright\alpha]$, by homogeneity of the tail of the Levy collapse. Since $\kappa$ is weakly compact in $L[G\upharpoonright\alpha]$, and $T$ also has the right form in $L[G\upharpoonright\alpha]$, there is $b\in L[G\upharpoonright\alpha]$ which is a $T$-cofinal branch. But then $L[G\upharpoonright\alpha]\subseteq M$, so $b\in M$. Note we also have DC in $M$.

Thanks a lot. I should have tried this before posting the question...Is there a "metatheorem" on the sort of large cardinal properties that can be transferred to $\omega_1$? According to this answer, Jech's construction works for any large cardinal property that is preserved under small forcing and is of the form $\forall X\exists Y\ \phi(X,Y)$, where $\phi$ is something upward absolute. Your argument seems to work in this generality too?

Yes, it does seem to work in that generality.
